# Show sysdate + 7 on a specific spot in a page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I am selling a product with a 7 day free trial.
On the landing page I want to tell them they will not be charged today rather 7 days from today show the actual .

How can this be achieved? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime function to create the required time window.

```
echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime("+7 days"));
```

Comment: But this cannot be used on a Wordpress page, since it accept only HTML.